# How to verify the RPM database?

Tags: opensuse, rpm

I need to verify that the RPM database (not an RPM, the database in `/var/lib/rpm`) is not corrupt or inconsistent, in a manner suitable for scripting (i.e. will return exit code 0 if good and something else if corrupt).  I can use `db_verify` to verify the individual Berkeley databases, but suppose the individual Berkeley databases are totally valid and the inconsistency is across databases. I experimented by deleting (renaming) a database, and `rpm -qa --dump` was oblivious and `rpm -Va` just regenerated it with a warning.  I suppose I could look for the string "warning:" in the output, but that seems unreliable.  Besides I don't really want to verify the files, I want to verify the database.  I've searched for OpenSuSE RPM-related packages and found nothing apropos.  Any suggestions?  I'd prefer something designed to do a thorough verification as opposed to just a dump.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an undocumented `--verifydb` flag that's been around since at least rpm-4.1.

See [`rpm/rpmdb.c`](http://rpm.org/gitweb?p=rpm.git;a=blob;f=rpmdb.c;hb=HEAD#l23):

```
{ "verifydb", '\0', (POPT_ARG_VAL|POPT_ARGFLAG_OR|POPT_ARGFLAG_DOC_HIDDEN),
    &mode, MODE_VERIFYDB, N_("verify database files"), NULL},
```

So `rpm --verifydb` should do exactly what you're looking for.